# Links not working when using ngFor loop with pageScroll attribute

Tags: angular

I'm using `ng2-page-scroll` package for smooth scrolling anchor jump. While using pageScroll attribute with `ngFor` loop, the link isn't working. I think because the `href` attribute is getting replaced with the `ng-reflect-href`.

**Source code:**

```
<a *ngFor="let section of sections" pageScroll [pageScrollOffset]="50" [pageScrollDuration]="300" [href]="'#'+section.sectionName">{{section.sectionName}}</a>
```

**Output:**

```
<a _ngcontent-c1="" pagescroll="" ng-reflect-href="#PATIENT IDENTIFICATION" ng-reflect-page-scroll-offset="50" ng-reflect-page-scroll-duration="300" ng-reflect-page-scroll="">PATIENT IDENTIFICATION</a>
```

If I remove the pageScroll attribute the link starts functioning normally.

**Source code:**

```
<a *ngFor="let section of sections" [href]="'#'+section.sectionName">{{section.sectionName}}</a>
```

**Output:**

```
<a _ngcontent-c1="" href="#PATIENT IDENTIFICATION">PATIENT IDENTIFICATION</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed to check the obvious thing. The scroll targets `<div id="patientIdentification">` was missing on the page that's why the link wasn't working.